# Lucene is limiting the query terms

Tags: java, lucene, morelikethis

I'm trying to use Lucene (5.4.1) MoreLikeThis to tag(classify) texts. It's kind of working, but I'm getting poor results, and I think that the problem is related with the Query object.

The example bellow works, but the highest topdoc isn't the one that I expect. By debuging the query object, it shows only `content:erro`. From a complete portuguese phrase (see into the example) the query was constructed with just one word.

I'm not using stop words or any other kind of filter.

So why lucene is picking just **erro** as a query term?

**To init main objects**

```
Analyzer analyzer = new PortugueseAnalyzer();

Directory indexDir = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
```

**To index**

```
try (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config)) {
   FieldType type = new FieldType();
   type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
   type.setStored(true);
   type.setStoreTermVectors(true);

   Document doc = new Document();
   doc.add(new StringField("id", "880b2bbc", Store.YES));
   doc.add(new Field("content", "erro", type));
   doc.add(new Field("tag", "atag", type));

   indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
   indexWriter.commit();
}
```

**To search**

```
    try (IndexReader idxReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir)) {
       IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(idxReader);

       MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(idxReader);
       mlt.setMinTermFreq(0);
       mlt.setMinDocFreq(0);
       mlt.setFieldNames(new String[] { "content" });
       mlt.setAnalyzer(analyzer);

       Reader sReader = new StringReader("Melhorias no controle de sessão no sistema qquercoisa quando expira, ao logar novamente no sistema é exibido o erro "xpto");

       Query query = mlt.like("content", sReader);

       TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to take a look inside MoreLokeThis class and I found the answer.

The `Query query = mlt.like("content", sReader);` call the `createQueue(Map<String, Int> words)` method in MoreLokeThis class.

Inside it, the tokenized terms/words from `sReader` (that were converted to a `Map`) are checked against the index.

Only terms/words that are present into the index are used to create a query.

Using the example that I provided, since my index contains only a document with the word **erro**, this is the only word that is kept from the phrase that I passed.